# Upload file to Google Drive from URL using REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, file-upload, google-drive-api

It is possible to upload a file from a URL using OneDrive's REST API as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_upload_url). This API accepts the URL we provide and uploads the file from the URL to the intended destination.

I have been trying to find a similar REST API or library for Google Drive, but I couldn't find it yet. Kindly direct me on how to achieve this. I have already set up oAuth and am able to receive access_token and refresh_token. Uploading files from URL is an important functionality in this project.

The project is hosted in Heroku, so I can't download the file to a temporary file and upload that file. It is a NodeJS project.

Comment: You can upload using files.create in Drive API. The detail information is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create).

Comment: @Tanaike, I couldn't find anywhere in this document on how to pass a url as argument to make a simple upload.

Comment: How about this? https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads

Comment: you mean, create readstream from the url and use the stream in the sdk method ?

Comment: Uploading Files files in Drive API using REST is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads).

You can send upload requests in any of the following ways:

Simple upload, Multipart upload, Resumable upload.

Comment: @noogui Yes, but none of these methods use a url as a param. They need a file object or a stream. The one drive api I mentioned can accept a url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for this solution. however, what I understand from other blog and articles is you have to download File from provided URL on your server then upload it to google drive.

As of now, i understand this. Will update this if I able to do this.

Comment: This is the way I implemented it. Piped the stream to the post request.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are unable to use OneDrive's REST API on Google Drive since most such services are self-used only.
Yet, i know a third party online app which enables you [upload files](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/upload-file-via-url-1234.html) to most common cloud drives (Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox, Mega, etc.) from URL links. What you have to do is to create an account of this web-based app, add your cloud to its platform and import/export files to your cloud through its service. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Its quite obvious that I cannot upload files to Google Drive by using OneDrive API. I am requesting information regarding an equivalent GoogleDrive API to the mentioned OneDrive API. That is, a file upload API that accept a URL as a parameter.

Comment: If so, i'm afraid i can't help.