# UrlFetchApp Truncates Downloads

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an issue where every time I request file via `UrlFetchApp` it truncates the file to `20mb` (`20,971,520 bytes`)

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://example.com/My150mbFile.dat");
var blob = response.getBlob();
var createdFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
```

How could I work around this?

Comment: I suppose it's by design, and the only way around is to split the file. The [quotas/limitations page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) does not state this limit (although for POST requests it is stated as 10MB) but it's not unusual for Google to have a quota that isn't documented.

Comment: You could get creative and try to directly upload to Drive from the remote resource. Unfortunately, I am not sure that you will be successful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408090/upload-file-to-google-drive-from-url-using-rest-api

Comment: Thanks for the links. It gave me the idea of trying Azure Apps Workflow (Http request->Http download->Create file) basically creating an API. However, it seems Workflows have a limit: `Http request failed as there is an error: 'Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 104857600.'.`  (104mb)